# npm ffmpeg-binaries failed install

Tags: node.js, npm, ffmpeg

**Problem**

> Failed at the ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install script 'node install'

**How I do it**

```
npm i ffmpeg-binaries
```

**Environment**

Ubuntu 14 on VDS

Node v6.0.0

NVM v3.8.6

**Last string of npm-debug**

```
    9491 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
    9492 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
    9493 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
    9494 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
    9495 silly install printInstalled
    9496 warn root@1.0.0 No description
    9497 warn root@1.0.0 No repository field.
    9498 verbose stack Error: ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install: `node install`
    9498 verbose stack Exit status 137
    9498 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:239:16)
    9498 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    9498 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    9498 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    9498 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    9498 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    9498 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    9498 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
    9499 verbose pkgid ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0
    9500 verbose cwd /root
    9501 error Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2
    9502 error argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/bin/npm" "i" "ffmpeg-binaries"
    9503 error node v6.0.0
    9504 error npm  v3.8.6
    9505 error code ELIFECYCLE
    9506 error ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install: `node install`
    9506 error Exit status 137
    9507 error Failed at the ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install script 'node install'.
    9507 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    9507 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ffmpeg-binaries package,
    9507 error not with npm itself.
    9507 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    9507 error     node install
    9507 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    9507 error     npm bugs ffmpeg-binaries
    9507 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    9507 error     npm owner ls ffmpeg-binaries
    9507 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    9508 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also recently been having this error, but I have since solved it. The thing you need to do is use the command:

```
npm install ffbinaries
```

instead of using `ffmpeg-binaries.`
The reason for this is because the binaries were originally created for ubuntu linux. Hope this helps! :)